# How to load JavaScript in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm using [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com) in my app and I can't load it from assets in to WebView

here is my code:

```
WebView webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/ckeditor/samples/index.html");
```

The index page loaded by JavaScript works fine (I tested with alert()) and so does the CSS. But the text area which suppose to load Ckeditor is not working.

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
```

I also tried from remote host. It works fine with Device Browser in case I request desktop version

Comment: warning: android in-app webviews are not intended to be used for interactive tasks. even if you solve this particular problem you will still have issues. You may need to change your approach. Someone mentioned `CocoonJS` to me recently, a more advanced webview but I haven't used it yet

Comment: @CQM Thanks for advice, Im looking after it.